# Are GIS Analyst salaries going to always be so low?

Tags: analysis

I regularly see GIS Analyst job postings (often in very expensive cities) asking for a plethora of experience paying in the $40k - 60k a year range, many are even below $40k or $30k.

Considering the amount of patience it takes to deal with Esri software and all of the work-arounds one must routinely implement GIS professionals are being severely underpaid.

Are the majority of GIS Analysts independently wealthy and just do GIS for fun?
I do not see any other logical reason for the low pay reality GIS Analysts are in.

Has there ever been an attempt to create a GIS Union?

Comment: Depends where in the world you are comparing to? $40-60k is not low depending on what you define as a normal/high wage.

Comment: This sometimes reflects a lack of awareness by HR/hiring managers of the level of skill required -- "GIS Analyst" can cover a range of tasks, from simple data maintenance and updates (which can be done with minimal training/experience so $30-40k is reasonable) to complex analysis and data management (which typically requires more education/experience, and demands a higher salary).

Comment: "lack of awareness by HR/hiring manager" should not be acceptable. We need a GIS Union to deal with this ridiculousness.

Comment: Then start one!

Comment: @user3396 I will gladly discuss creating a union... let me know how to get in touch with you!

Comment: @user3396 so if your on a low wage and paying into a union as a member - you end up with less money?

Comment: @mapBaker I sent you an email through your web site.

Comment: @Mapperz  the main purposes of Unions is to stand up for employees and make sure they are not being exploited. A nominal Union fee pays for itself x1000 assuming the Union has some teeth.

Comment: right on @user3396!

Comment: Since my question is apparently censorship-worthy. Can the mods please recommend another GIS forum where this question can be asked without the said issues?

Comment: @user3396 watching.

Comment: There is no censoring going on: this question simply is not on topic here, as our [help] explains.  For some hard *data* you might want to turn to trade articles such as http://www.directionsmag.com/articles/what-do-gis-consultants-charge/124152 and http://www.directionsmag.com/articles/how-much-do-gis-consultants-charge-in-2011/176035.  As far as discussion of a union goes, or griping about salaries, or other such speculation, our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis) would be a good place to strike up that conversation.

Comment: This is most certainly censorship by anti-union advocates. Please tell us why threads like this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/why-do-you-use-arcgis-for-desktop/6675#6675 do not fall into the "not on topic" and "entirely based on opinions" censorship-worthy classification? There dozens of other example threads too. Just search using "best" and "software".

Comment: The lack of appropriate tags (employment, salary, job, etc.) indicates it is not really suited to GIS.SE, despite community interest. Perhaps it could be migrated to http://workplace.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4):

GIS is still a relatively new technology, despite its exploding popularity and application potential, and so it will take time for HR to understand exactly what GIS is for, what a GIS "Analyst" does, and what they should be paid. However, if they see data from reputable national organizations that indicate higher pay is typical (and they will therefore attract better candidates), things can change.

Many professional societies strive to provide information about appropriate salary and job titles. While not really *unions* (they don't *negotiate* on behalf of their membership), their research on salary trends can be used for negotiation either during hiring or performance reviews. A couple examples that I'm immediately aware of:

- Association of American Geographers (AAG) [Salary Data and Trends for Geography Careers](http://www.aag.org/cs/salarydata)
- Urban and Regional Information Systems Association (URISA) [Salary Survey for IT/GIS Professionals](http://www.urisa.org/clientuploads/directory/Documents/Books%20and%20Quick%20Study/OverallFindings11.pdf)

URISA's surveys show that a GIS *Technician* -- typically the individual who's doing just data entry or maintenance -- averages $40k, while a GIS *Analyst* is at least $10k higher. (I have found that AAG's data, which is drawn from the US Bureau of Labor Statistics, is often... [optimistic](http://www.aag.org/cs/Salary_Data_and_Trends/Professional_Scientific_and_Technical_Services/15-1099.07).)

Comment: Also the amount you earn and the amount you are taxed - uk is at least 22% of your wage is taxed. Then there is the tax on products food/clothes you buy... another 20% http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxation_in_the_United_Kingdom#Income_tax http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxation_in_the_United_Kingdom#Value_added_tax

Comment: The explosion of popularity should be considered past-tense. My impression is such that we now increasingly supply more GIS graduates than there are jobs available. 

Take a look at this graph - http://www.indeed.com/jobtrends?q=gis&l=

It makes for a grim outlook. While it's true more businesses are adopting GIS for their own ends, the pace is decelerating, and established GIS depts. don't hire much. All this means employers can keep wages lower with relative ease.

Comment: @Sleep6 Largely true. Perhaps a better phrasing would be "despite increased awareness of its usefulness among non-geographers"?

Comment: That seems accurate.

Answer (score 4):

It's important to note the job titles associated with positions that supersede GIS Technician or GIS Analyst. You won't (hopefully) find too many job postings looking to hire for a GIS Analyst position with the requirement of 10 years of experience.

After 5-8 years as a GIS Analyst you would likely start looking to transition to a GIS Coordinator/GIS Manager/Team Lead role or, alternatively, you would become more specialized (Lead GIS Developer, GIS Systems Architect, Senior Programmer/Analyst).

In the case of smaller companies without the traditional upward mobility in GIS job titles you might take on the role of a Project Manager in addition to your Analyst responsibilities.

As others have mentioned, GIS is still a relatively new field in the eyes of HR and therefore the structure you might find with other specific jobs (e.g. Engineer, Programmer) is not yet fully developed. The good news is, there is plenty of room to develop your own career path.